# Is a pronoun needed before the verb if the direct object is "toi-même"?

Tags: grammaire, emphase, pronoms-réfléchis

I was looking at this sentence:

> Chaque fois que tu as fait du tort à quelqu’un, tu te faisais du tort à toi-même.

The second bit, *tu te faisais du tort à toi-même*, I am slightly unsure about the grammar. I would have thought I could write *tu faisais du tort à toi-même*, without the *te*.

If the direct object is *moi-même*, *toi-même*, *soi-même*, or the like, is it always still necessary to use the reflexive pronoun also?

Comment: You might want to change what you name Direct Object to Indirect Object in the light of the preposition standing in front of *toi-même*. Both in the question and in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**C'est un pléonasme (une répétition), pour renforcer encore plus sur qui porte l'action (faire du tort). Ce n'est pas obligatoire.**

On peut dire simplement:

> Tu **te** faisais du tort. (qui remplace : *tu faisais du tort à toi*, qu'on ne devrait pas employer).
>
> Tu faisais du tort **à toi-même**. (insistance).

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax: Dites-vous que le deuxième exemple doit être, "Tu te faisais du tort à toi-même"?

Comment: Merci, j'ai pensé que le _te_ n'est pas necessaire. Je dois en plus penser. :) 
p.s. Excusez-moi pour des erreurs. J'apprends la langue.

Comment: C'est génial, merci beaucoup.

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax , les constructions "à toi", "à moi", ne devraient pas être employées (j'ai changé "ne doit pas" en "ne devrait pas"), et remplacées par te, me, ...  Mais ce n'est pas possible avec toi-même. Mais cela reste très lourd.

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax - il est clair que c'est très lourd, mais je ne vois pas d'autres moyens pour pouvoir dire de manière renforcée "à toi-même", par un pronom placé en tête. Nécessité fait loi. On doit donc accepter cet usage.